# A function encode to convert a number in base 10 to a number in base 'b' don't print nothing

Tags: c

I created this function to convert a number 'd' in base 10 to a number x in base 'b', unfortunately the function does not print, could someone help me?

```
// I don't understand why it doesn't print me the encode 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
// the function created to convert a number 'd' in base 10 to a number in base 'b'
char *encode(unsigned int d, unsigned char b){
    if(b<2||b>16) return NULL;
    char * resto = calloc (SIZE, sizeof(char));
    int i=1;
    while(d>0){//rimanenza d%b 
        char rimanenza = d%b ;
        d = d/b;
        if (b>10 && b<=16){//if the base is between 10 and 16 'rimanenza' can't be a number
            if (rimanenza == 10) rimanenza = 'A';
            if (rimanenza == 11) rimanenza = 'B';
            if (rimanenza == 12) rimanenza = 'C';
            if (rimanenza == 13) rimanenza = 'D';
            if (rimanenza == 14) rimanenza = 'E';
            if (rimanenza == 15) rimanenza = 'F';
        }// save into resto from the end 
        resto [SIZE - i] = rimanenza;
        i++;
    }

    return resto  ;
    
}

int main (){
    unsigned int d = 126;
    unsigned char b = 3;    
    char *encoded = encode (d,b);
    printf ("%u in base %u = %s\n",d,b,encoded);
    free(encoded);
}
```

Comment: yeah, you should fill your string with blanks first

Comment: If `rimanenza` is below ten, it will not represent an ASCII value. In that case, your string will contain unprintable values. You probably need `if (rim < 10) rim = '0' + rim;` somewhere in the inner loop.

Comment: (It's not your immediate problem, but a size of 20 is not enough to print all unsigned 32-bit numbers in bases 2 and 3.)

Comment: Don't try to `printf()` from a NULL string pointer... Need more protection...

Comment: In fact, `if (b>10 && b<=16)` can go away completely... After the modulo operation, all you are interested in is converting the value of `rimanenza` to an ASCII character...

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Digit not converted to correct character when `rimanenza < 10`**

When `rimanenza` is in the [0...9] range, convert it to characters ['0'...'9'].

```
rimanenza += '0';
```

**`while(d>0){` fails to form `"0"` when `d` originally 0.**

**Return wrong offset**

`return resto  ;` fails to return the beginning of the populated part of `resto[]`.

More like:

```
// return resto  ;
return memmove(resto, &resto[SIZE - i - 1], SIZE - i);
```

**Fails to test if `calloc()` failed**

**Size too small**

`#define SIZE 20` is insufficient for `encode(UINT_MAX, 2)`. [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321648/a-function-encode-to-convert-a-number-in-base-10-to-a-number-in-base-b-dont-p/75322920#comment132907965_75321648)

**Lack of trailing *null character***

Code needs a `'\0'` after all the characters to be a *string*.

**Code allocation is not sized to the data**

Consider only allocating what is needed.

---

Untested repairs

```
#include <limits.h>
#define ENCODE_SZ (sizeof (unsigned) * CHAR_BIT + 1)  // Size buffer to base 2 worst case

char* encode(unsigned d, unsigned b) {
  if (b < 2 || b > 16) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char buffer[ENCODE_SZ];
  char *p = &buffer[ENCODE_SZ - 1]; // Point to last array element.
  *p = '\0'; // Terminate array with a null character.

  // Use a do loop to make sure code assigns at least 1 character.
  do {
    unsigned digit = d % b;
    // Look-up character;
    char ch = "0123456789ABCDEF"[digit];
    p--;
    *p = ch;
    d /= b;
  } while (d > 0);

  // Determine string length
  unsigned length = &buffer[ENCODE_SZ - 1] - p;
  unsigned size = length + 1;
  char *resto = malloc(size);
  if (resto == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // Copy and return.
  return strcpy(resto, p);
}
```